# Start Slideshow On Image Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple slideshow I'm creating using jQuery for a Peruvian client at [www.hostalandenes.com](http://www.hostalandenes.com/). We have a relatively unique problem here in Peru that the internet tends to be extremely slow, and I think the slideshow looks cheesy when it starts and the images are only 10% loaded.

Is there a way to trigger the start of the slideshow only when the images have loaded? I tried to trigger the start of the slideshow with a load binding to the first image, but that only triggered when the image is actually loaded from the server, and not from the cache.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just using the `$(window).load` trigger, and it works fine.